# HashCode implementation for class whose all instances are equal

Tags: java, hashcode, equality

Suppose I have a class where all instances are considered equal. A typical use case is for classes that do not have any state, but only behave as functions.

```
public class ToStringFunction implements Function<Object, String> {

    @Override
    public String apply(Object o) {
        return o.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof ToStringFunction;
    }
}
```

Now, how should one implement a hashCode method? Naturally, it needs to be a constant value in order to honor the equals/hashCode contract. But what value should that be? If some trivial value such as 0 or 1 was used, it could lead to collisions with other similar classes.

So it seems that this boils down to the question: *how to implement a hashCode that is likely to be unique for a given class, but the same for all of its instances*.

I came up with these two ideas. What do you think, are they sane?

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return ToStringFunction.class.hashCode();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return "ToStringFunction".hashCode();
}
```

Comment: The class based approach looks fine to me... But what do you need equals/hashCode for if I may ask?

Comment: I think you don't need to put objects into a set when they have no state just functions.

Comment: I don't have a concrete use case, but I suppose you might want to have a set of operations that you want to apply on some data. For example, the JDK Comparator defines equals in its interface: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Answer (score 7):

If a class does not have state, it should be a singleton, an abstract class, or a repository of static methods (like Math). Therefore, it makes no sense to override equals and hashcode for it.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the serial version id (cast it down to integer). That will be a unique number for each class.

What you are trying to do doesn't really make a huge amount of sense though without more context being provided. If these objects are stateless then just make them either a singleton (if you do need an instance due for example using them as strategies in a strategy pattern) or make all the methods static if you don't need an instance.

I guess if they are strategies all implementing the same interface then being able to compare them would make sense, but if each implementation is a singleton then the default `Object` `equals` and `hashCode` methods will do everything you need.

Comment: _...if each implementation is a singleton then the default Object equals and hashCode methods will do everything you need._ good point.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a "legitimate" (at least for me! :-P) use case for this: I have a hierachy of classes where some child ones have state and others don't have. Anyway i want to use a `Map<BaseClass,Value>` and use all instances of `ChildClassWihtoutState extends BaseClass` as a unique key of the map without add an special `getInstance()`.

So, what about use the hash of the qualified class name string? It should be unique within a jvm, right?

```
public int hashCode() {
   return getClass().getName().hashCode();
}
```